# Wait for the background jobs to finish before continuing

Tags: shell, sh

I want to compile files that are contained in a directory hierarchy.
Like this one: `tree src`

```
src
├── dir0
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang
│   ├── subdir3
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile2.lang
│   │   └── subsubdir10
│   │       ├── srcfile100.lang
│   │       └── srcfile102.lang
│   └── subdir4
│       ├── srcfile0.lang
│       ├── srcfile1.lang
│       ├── srcfile2.lang
│       └── subsubdir11
│           ├── srcfile101.lang
│           └── srcfile102.lang
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang
│   ├── subdir3
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang
│   │   ├── srcfile2.lang
│   │   └── subsubdir11
│   │       ├── srcfile100.lang
│   │       └── srcfile101.lang
│   └── subdir4
│       ├── srcfile0.lang
│       ├── srcfile1.lang
│       ├── srcfile2.lang
│       └── subsubdir10
│           ├── srcfile100.lang
│           └── srcfile102.lang
├── dir2
│   ├── subdir0
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang
│   └── subdir3
│       ├── srcfile0.lang
│       └── srcfile1.lang
├── srcfile06.lang
├── srcfile07.lang
└── srcfile08.lang

16 directories, 33 files
```

Each file is independent of the others. I want to compile this hierarchy in another directory called "build", like this: `tree build`

```
build
├── dir0
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang.out
│   ├── subdir3
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile2.lang.out
│   │   └── subsubdir10
│   │       ├── srcfile100.lang.out
│   │       └── srcfile102.lang.out
│   └── subdir4
│       ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│       ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│       ├── srcfile2.lang.out
│       └── subsubdir11
│           ├── srcfile101.lang.out
│           └── srcfile102.lang.out
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang.out
│   ├── subdir3
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│   │   ├── srcfile2.lang.out
│   │   └── subsubdir11
│   │       ├── srcfile100.lang.out
│   │       └── srcfile101.lang.out
│   └── subdir4
│       ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│       ├── srcfile1.lang.out
│       ├── srcfile2.lang.out
│       └── subsubdir10
│           ├── srcfile100.lang.out
│           └── srcfile102.lang.out
├── dir2
│   ├── subdir0
│   │   ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│   │   └── srcfile2.lang.out
│   └── subdir3
│       ├── srcfile0.lang.out
│       └── srcfile1.lang.out
├── srcfile06.lang.out
├── srcfile07.lang.out
└── srcfile08.lang.out

16 directories, 33 files
```

When I have the first hierarchy, I want to have the last one with all the compilable files compiled and stored in the "build" hierarchy.

I have written this script to do this.

`cat mycompiler`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

CURRENTDIR="$(dirname -- \""$(readlink -f \""${O}\"")\"")"
SRCDIR="${1:-$CURRENTDIR}"
BUILDDIR="$(dirname \""${SRCDIR}\"")/build"

# compile build hierarchy
COMPILER="cat"
OPTION=""
INPUTEXT=".lang"
OUTPUTSUCCESSEXT=".out"
OUTPUTFAILUREEXT=".log"

compile () {
  f="${1}"
  dir=$(dirname -- "${f}" | sed "s#${SRCDIR}#${BUILDDIR}#")
  mkdir -p "${dir}"
  success=$(echo "${f}" | sed "s#${SRCDIR}#${BUILDDIR}#;s#\(${INPUTEXT}\)#\1${OUTPUTSUCCESSEXT}#")
  failure=$(echo "${f}" | sed "s#${SRCDIR}#${BUILDDIR}#;s#\(${INPUTEXT}\)#\1${OUTPUTFAILUREEXT}#")
  #echo "${COMPILER} ${f} >${success} 2>${failure}"
  "${COMPILER}" "${OPTION}" "${f}" >"${success}" 2>"${failure}"
}


find "${SRCDIR}" -type f -iname "*${INPUTEXT}" | while IFS= read -r f
do
  compile "${f}" &
done

find "${BUILDDIR}" -type f -iname "*${OUTPUTFAILUREEXT}" -empty -exec rm {} \;

exit 0
```

As the files are independent, I want it to happen in parallel to speed up the process, but only in the while loop.

The last two commands of the script (see below) need to wait for all background tasks to finish.

```bash
find "${BUILDDIR}" -type f -iname "*${OUTPUTFAILUREEXT}" -empty -exec rm {} \;

exit 0
```

Can anyone help me improve my script?

thanks ^^

Comment: Halting until background jobs finish is what the `wait` command is for. (You have some bugs here with filenames containing newline literals, btw, but they're hard to avoid when strict POSIX compatibility is a requirement).

Comment: BTW, skip the bash tag if you'll only accept sh-compatible answers.

Comment: Another note: POSIX guidelines specify that all-caps names are used by variables that modify behavior of the shell and other POSIX-specified tools, whereas variable names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use. In this context, your script is an application, so it should use lowercase names for variables defined for its own use. Read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the same conventions necessarily apply to both.

Comment: Also, why are you adding _literal_ quotes in `CURRENTDIR="$(dirname -- \""$(readlink -f \""${O}\"")\"")"`? Those are wrong. You only need extra backslashes with legacy backtick command substitution syntax, not with `$()`; in the latter it's just `CURRENTDIR="$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f "$0")")"` because each command substitution starts a new quoting context. Same in your code setting `BUILDDIR` as well.

Answer (score 1):

the usual way to use `wait` to wait for all background jobs to finish is hidden by the function compile().

It makes the code ugly, but if you pull the content of compile() into your main script, doing a `wait` will work.

and: some versions of `sh` and `bash` require the job control to be explicitly turned on by using `set -m`

Comment: `wait` will only ever need job control if you don't do the work of tracking PIDs yourself. If you keep a list of PIDs (`foo & foo_pids="$foo_pids $!"` in sh -- in bash of course I'd suggest using a proper array instead), then you can pass those PIDs as arguments to `wait` even if the shell itself isn't keeping track of subprocesses.